# Can I use GCM for a chrome EXTENSION?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, push-notification

I'm new to web development and currently I'm trying to create a chrome extension.

I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web) google tutorial  and also [this one](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/) and [this one](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client) but for some reason the push notifications does not work when I define the extension as an extension and not as an application.

Can anyone give some guidance? my code is basically identical to the [2nd](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/) tutorial only I am defining the extensions as an extension and not as an application.

To my understanding it might be impossible due to safety reasons(?)..
Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: **Always** start with debugging. Each page in a chrome extension has its own debugger window. Use breakpoints, step through the code, inspect the variables.

Answer (score 1):

**Can I use GCM for a chrome EXTENSION?**

Yes you can. GCM docs states that:

> For Chrome apps and extensions, GCM enables Chrome instances to send
>   and receive message data from servers. The
>   [chrome.gcm](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/gcm) API allows the
>   Chrome apps or extensions to access the GCM service. The service works
>   even if an app or extension isn't currently running. For example,
>   calendar updates could be pushed to users even when their calendar app
>   isn't open.

Receive downstream messages

```
chrome.gcm.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
// A message is an object with a data property that
// consists of key-value pairs.
});
```

There's also a [dev blog guide](http://hayageek.com/google-cloud-messaging-for-chrome/) that you might want to see. It includes sample codes and instructions like:

How push messaging works

```
1) Chrome extension gets a Channel ID from Chrome Run-time
2) After receiving Channel ID, your extension sends the channel ID to your web server.
3) Using GCM API, you can send a message to chrome browser which will queued in GCM Server.
4) GCM server sends your message to Chrome Run-time.
5) Chrome Run-time forwards the message to your extension.
```